# Зная id дочернего элемента, добавить html-контент в родительский

Tags: jquery

Зная id дочернего элемента, нужно добавить в родительский html-контент. Как это можно реализовать?
Информации о родительском элементе никакой нет.

jQuery.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
// Добавит DIV в #parent после элемента #children
$('#children').after('<div/>'); 

// Добавит DIV в #parent до элемента #children
$('#children').before('<div/>');
```

Либо выбрать родительский компонент через дочерний и добавлять напрямую к нему:

```
// Определяем родителя
let $parent = $('#children').parent(); 

// Добавляем DIV в конец #parent
$parent.append('<div/>');

// Добавляем DIV в начало #parent// Добавляем DIV в начало #parent
$parent.prepend('<div/>');
```